# An example of a differentiable function but not Lipschitz continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a example of a differentiable function that is not Lipschitz, and I think if a function has no bounded derivative, it is not Lipschitz continuous.

Let $f(x)=\log x$ on $(0,\infty)$. By mean value theorem, $$\begin{align}\left| f(x)-f(0)\right|=\frac{1}{c}|x|  \text{ for some $c$ between $x$ and $0$} .\end{align}$$
Let $x\to 0$, then $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous.
Am I correct?

Comment: Your function is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$, just on $(0,\infty)$. Besides that, yes.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ is a simpler example.

Comment: @ClementC. thanks

Comment: It is true that if $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is differentiable and $f'$ is unbounded then $f $ is not Lipschitz. But $f$ can be Lipschitz and nowhere differentiable

Answer (score 2):

Try $f(x) = x^2 \sin { 1\over x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0.$ This is differentiable everywhere but the derivative is unbounded on any neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As Clement said on his comment, your function is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Take a look at $f(x) = x^2$ for example. Can you see why this function is differentiable but not Lipschitz continuous? Take $x$ sufficiently large, and the derivative will pass any bound you like.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as a solution to your question if you believe it is such. This will help future readers find it more easily.