Does a function that is differentiable at a point satisfy the Lipschitz condition around that point?
If I have a function $f(x)$ defined on a compact interval, which is differentiable at the point $x=x_0$, does it follow that it satisfies the Lipschitz condition around that point? As in, is it true that there exists a constant $C$ such that for every $x$, $$\left| f(x+x_0)-f(x_0) \right| \le C\left | x \right| $$ holds?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3947823

The Lipschitz condition around $x_0$ should be
$$\left| f(x + x_0) - f(x_0)\right| \le C |x| $$
for $x$ such that $x + x_0$ is in the interval.

It is true, by the definition of derivative, for $|x|$ sufficiently small, but not necessarily for all  $x$ such that $x + x_0$ is in the interval.  For example, there's nothing to prevent $\lim_{x \to p} f(x + x_0) = \infty$ for some $p$.
